# ¿Qué tengo que hacer para que mi app en Android Studio no dé el error de "has stopped"?

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy comenzando a hacer una aplicación en Android Studio y llevo poco tiempo con esto. Trato de hacer una list view y poder pinchar en cada item de la list view para mostrar un detalle de cada uno de los item, tengo el siguiente código del fragmento del detalle:

```js
public class GestoresDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_GESTOR_ID = "gestorId";

    private String mGestorId;

    private TextView mHorasTotales;
    private TextView mLocalizadosRealizados;
    private TextView mActivacionesExtra;
    private TextView mHorasNoche;


    private GestoresDbHelper mGestoresDbHelper;

    public GestoresDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static GestoresDetailFragment newInstance(String gestorId) {
        GestoresDetailFragment fragment = new GestoresDetailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_GESTOR_ID, gestorId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
           mGestorId=getArguments().getString(ARG_GESTOR_ID);
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gestores_detail, container, false);
        mHorasTotales=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.tv_horas_totales);
        mLocalizadosRealizados=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.tv_localizados);
        mActivacionesExtra=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.tv_activaciones_extra);
        mHorasNoche=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.tv_horas_noche);

        mGestoresDbHelper = new GestoresDbHelper(getActivity());

        loadGestores();

        return root;
    }

    private void loadGestores() {
        new GetGestoresByTask().execute();
    }

    private void showGestores(Gestores gestores){
        mHorasTotales.setText(gestores.getHorasTotales());
        mHorasNoche.setText(gestores.getHorasNoche());
        mActivacionesExtra.setText(gestores.getActivacionExtra());
        mLocalizadosRealizados.setText(gestores.getLocalizados());
    }
    private void showLoadError(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Error al cargar la informacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private class GetGestoresByTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {
             return mGestoresDbHelper.getGestoresById(mGestorId);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor){
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToLast()){
                showGestores(new Gestores(cursor));
            }
            else {
                showLoadError();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        //Acciones
    }
}
```

Además, en el fragmento del activity principal tengo:

```js
public class GestoresFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int REQUEST_UPDATE_DELETE_GESTORES = 2;
    private GestoresDbHelper mGestoresDbHelper;

     private ListView mGestoresList;
     private GestoresCursorAdapter mGestoresAdapter;
     private FloatingActionButton mAddButton;



    public GestoresFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static GestoresFragment newInstance() {
        return new GestoresFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gestores, container, false);

        //Referencias
        mGestoresList=(ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.gestores_list);
        mGestoresAdapter= new GestoresCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
        mAddButton = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);

        //Setup
        mGestoresList.setAdapter(mGestoresAdapter);

        mGestoresList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Cursor currentItem = (Cursor) mGestoresAdapter.getItem(i);
                    String currentGestorId = currentItem.getString(
                            currentItem.getColumnIndex(GestoresEntry.ID));

                    showDetailScreen(currentGestorId);
                }

        });






        // Instancia de helper
        mGestoresDbHelper = new GestoresDbHelper(getActivity());
        
        // Carga de datos
        loadGestores();



        return root;
    }

    private void loadGestores() {
        new GestoresLoadTask().execute();
    }
    private void showDetailScreen(String GestorId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GestoresDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_GESTORES_ID,GestorId);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_UPDATE_DELETE_GESTORES);
    }

    private class GestoresLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return mGestoresDbHelper.getAllGestores();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor){
            if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
                mGestoresAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            } else {
                //Mostrar empty state
            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode){
            switch (requestCode){
                case REQUEST_UPDATE_DELETE_GESTORES:
                    loadGestores();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

El error me sale al compilar la aplicación pues me aparece un mensaje de no se pudo cargar. 
En principio no veo nada que necesite demasiada carga de computación y creo tener bien hechas las tareas asíncronas para evitar ese problema. 
No soy capaz de ver qué esta mal, he pensado que puede tener que ver con el layout, pero no veo nada extraño.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el `Logcat` para saber que es lo que te causa el error?

Comment: Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
Hola, me dice esto.